# Vs code create folder automatically with (dist) name

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In My VS code after each modifies create a folder with name `dist` in that directory, for example after in change something in folder  `foo/index.js` and save that changes, automatically 2 files appear in folder `foo/` with name `foo/index.dev.js` and `foo/index.prod.js`

how can I stop this ?

Comment: `dist` is a good folder; it's your build output.

Answer (score 37):

Solution

This Issue happens maybe you install Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile Hero
Plugin in your VS code and if you use this plugin, you can disable that for avoiding compile on save file and create `index.dev.js` and `index.prod.js` file

[image]

Comment: thanks its solved, it requires restart vs code after uninstall or disable this plugin.

Comment: For me it was another plugin (Code Spell Checker) that was causing the issue. Double check your plugins, thanks for pointing this out.