# ng serve: dist folder being generated on every app subfolder

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, tsconfig

I'm facing this issue since I've started the project and actually don't know if normal but annoying.

Dist folder is created with partial info related to the component that is inside that folder.

- dashboard

  - dist (unwanted)
  - components
- panel

  - dist (unwanted)
  - components

[image: How it looks]

My aim is to avoid those folders, if possible and know why they appeared.
I've checked tsconfig.json file where

> "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc"

seems to be something different.

Comment: Is this the result of you running `npm run build` or `ng build`?

Comment: under what circumstances dist is created?

Comment: Try to do :  "outDir": "./"

Comment: It is created during ng serve, and once stopped doesn't disappear

Comment: Can you share `angular.json` please?

Comment: This is probably a angular.json or tsconfig.json issue

Comment: Hi guys I found out that was a plugin responsible for that. I really appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that it's actually a plugin that was doing this and had been answered here correctly.

[Vs code create folder automatically with (dist) name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179606/vs-code-create-folder-automatically-with-dist-name)

Thank you