# Nodemon Creating a dist folder on save

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-start

I am using **nodemon** in a straight forward express app, something has recently happened and every-time I save a child file in a folder, a `dist` folder is created and a child file created with the same name - with the addition of `.dev.` in the filename.

As far as I understand a `dist` file is created only once I finally compile the app for production - not when in development?

How can I stop the `dist` file from getting created each time I save?

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

i.e

**Before Save**

```
- routes
    - tests.route.js
```

**After Save**

```
- routes
   - dist
     - tests.route.dev.js
   - tests.route.js
```

Comment: dist is usually the "compiled" JS version of some TS code. Do you have any typescript files in the project? any `tsconfig.json` perhaps?

Comment: I did a search for any .ts files in the project incase I missed any. I can't see any!

Comment: wait by save do you mean it gets created every time you save your project?

Comment: Every time I save a file in the given folder - yes. It either creates a new .dev. file or overwrites one that has already been created - in the dist folder.

Comment: this feels more like an IDE problem rather than a Nodemon one. maybe one of your extensions is acting up? or maybe try with a different ide.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Based on your above suggesting I found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179606/vs-code-create-folder-automatically-with-dist-name Which has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a plugin called: Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile Hero Plugin with VScode, it was creating a new `dist` file on every save.

I followed this to fix it: [Vs code create folder automatically with (dist) name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179606/vs-code-create-folder-automatically-with-dist-name) - Basically you want to uninstall the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing it I follow these steps Given bellow and it is solved:-

1. Click on **Extensions** button of VS Code or press **Ctrl+Shift+X**.
2. Search for **Hero** Extension which shown bellow.
   [image]
3. Click on **Disable**.
4. Click on **Reloade**.