# Why is a folder named ".dist" automatically created in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I open a folder or create a workspace, VS Code automatically generates a ".dist" folder and it has been bugging me for quite a long time now and I still do not understand why it even exits in the first place.

It does not seem like there is any problem in deleting the folder.

For me, it is just some bloat that automatically generates when said conditions are met.

I would really like to find if there is a setting which I can toggle ON that disables the auto-generation of the ".dist" folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an extension you have installed which makes it to help with compliling or running. `Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile Hero Plugin` is probably the extension that does this.

Comment: Prior to posting the question, I have done some research and I found an answer which was similar to yours. 
You can find it here: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191700/17677808",
I have also noticed other people having the same problem but with a different extension.
And in my case, I have not installed the extension that you mentioned above.
So what would you suggest me to do which could solve my problem?

Comment: My answer still is the same. You should try disabling your extensions and test it out, or alternatively run vscode in safe mode. 
Using ```devenv.exe /SafeMode```allows you to run any version of visual studio (devenv.exe) in SafeMode that will disable 3rd party plugins. 

You can either run ```devenv.exe /SafeMode``` using the command line or by creating a new shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove the extension c compiler from your vs code.